# foreach loops - adding items once it's been initiated?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a question about PHP foreach loops. I'm using it in Codeigniter.

Basically I have a list of items in a db and I'm using a foreach loop to run a script on each item in the db until the script has been run on every item.

My question is: If I had, for example, 45 items in the database and then initiated the loop, what would happen if additional items were added to the database list while the loop was still running, thus making a bigger list of items to be looped over?

Would it either:
Run all the items that were in the loop when it was initiated (in this case, 45). 
or 
Run all the items in the loop and when it gets down to the end (at number 45) continue to run the script on the additional ones I added after the loop was initiated.

I can't seem to find any answers for this, any info is most appreciated

Comment: I don't see why don't you go ahead and try it?

Comment: once the query will be fired and you will run the forach loop on the fetched result ,no records will be added ,you have to select items again from the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch all items from the db with CodeIgniter, it puts the results in an result object or array, depending if you use `$this->db->result();` or `$this->db->result_array();`

So when you loop over this result, any new records won't show up in this object or array. Only when you fire a new query, any new rows will be added to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Initially when you fired a query their was 45 records in db and then record has been added , so there will be only 45 records which will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

When a php script run for extracting records from DB table, it actually extract all the records from table according to u'r query & save it in a PHP variable. After that, foreach loop extract data one by one from that variable & execute it.

At the execution time, if any more records comes to u'r DB table then that'll get store in u'r table not in u'r PHP array. So, forloop execution will not get effected by those extra rows.

If u want to execute, all those extra records.. then again u've to make SELECT query to the DB table & extract those additional records.. Need to keep them a PHP array & execute them by foreach.